# ClientBase and https connection. The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'. Parameter name: via

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, client

I'm trying to use the `ClientBase` class for communicating to a REST service. Below is my code:

```
class MyService: ClientBase<IMyService>, IMyService
{
    public GridVisionService(Uri baseAddress)
        : base(new WebHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(baseAddress))
    {
        this.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
    }

    #region IMyServiceMembers

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        using (new OperationContextScope(this.InnerChannel)) // Line that throws the exception
        {
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingRequest.Headers.Add("details", "details");
        } // End of OperationContextScope

        this.Channel.DoSomething();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I run my class like the following:

```
MyService myService = new MyService(new Uri("https://localhost:8080/MyService/"));
```

However, it throws the exception about expecting HTTP instead of HTTPS. On searching I've found multiple instances of the same error, however in all of the cases I have found the app.config is configuring the connection. In my case I am not. Does anyone know how I can make my service expect to use https?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create the WebHttpBinding, set its Security property to Transport.

```
System.ServiceModel.WebHttpBinding w = new System.ServiceModel.WebHttpBinding();
w.Security = new System.ServiceModel.WebHttpSecurity();
w.Security.Mode = System.ServiceModel.WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
```

Comment: I cannot seem to find a WebHttpsBinding class. The WebHttpBinding class is in the System.ServiceModel namespace, but there does not seem to be a WebHttpsBinding class.